# What's a good reference for improving my design workflow?

Tags: coding-style, uml

What's your method for dealing with the hard to grasp complexity of software? Are there any tools for automatically creating UML diagrams from code or something to that effect? Any way of going from diagrams to code?

Looking to make a serious overhaul to my workflow. I find myself doing tedious "non problem solving" coding more and more

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Altova](http://www.altova.com/umodel/uml-code-generation.html) is good and has a free trial

[Netbeans](http://blogs.oracle.com/JavaFundamentals/entry/generating_uml_from_the_netbeans) features a way to reverse engineer code to UML if your using Java

As does [Eclipse](http://www.myeclipseide.com/documentation/quickstarts/uml/#reverseengineering)